# Can you limit the max loudness (db) for audio output on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, audio

It happens very often that I am watching a video on Youtube or some other platform, and an advertisement starts suddenly, where the level is extremely high. And in case I had the volume control already high because of the low level of the video I am watching, my speakers or headphone bursts when the loud advertisement starts. I am surprised this problem hasn't been addressed at Youtube.

Is there a solution for MacOS or some little device for speakers or headphones to limit the output line at a specific db? I don't want to get hearing loss.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408611/85275 for a list of routing options for Mac. Of these, really only Soundsource is user-friendly enough to be able to do this quickly & with no prior knowledge of sound engineering. It has a simple 'volume optimiser' switch, but you can also add plugins [many available freeware, some are built into macOS itself] to limit this even harder. You're looking for a Compressor &/or Limiter. You could, of course, get a good ad-blocker too ;)